# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc is not converting old dates to then daylight saving time

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, utc

I'm using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc method to convert date time to the target date time. Current its UTC+10 in Sydney. If i run the code its perfectly converting time to UTC+10. But in Jan with out daylight saving It was UTC+11. If I input a Jan date run the code. Its still converting it as UTC+10 instead of UTC+11.

Below is the sample code.

```
      TimeZoneInfo ESTZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time");
      DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-23 13:15:23.6090752");
      DateTime SydneyDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Timezone));
      string EST = SydneyDateTime.ToString() + " / " + SydneyDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime().ToString() + " / " + ESTZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(SydneyDateTime)+" / " + ESTZone.DaylightName + " / " + ESTZone.StandardName;
      DateTime IndiaDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));


      DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-23 13:15:23.6090752");
      DateTime SydneyDateTime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date2, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Timezone));
      string EST2 = SydneyDateTime2.ToString() + " / " + SydneyDateTime2.IsDaylightSavingTime().ToString() + " / " + ESTZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(SydneyDateTime2) + " / " + ESTZone.DaylightName + " / " + ESTZone.StandardName;
```

Output Result:

EST = "23-01-2019 23:15:23 / False / False / E. Australia Summer Time / E. Australia Standard Time"

EST2="23-05-2019 23:15:23 / False / False / E. Australia Summer Time / E. Australia Standard Time"

In both the cases, its adding 10 hrs, but in January it should add 11 hrs.

Am I missing anything in the code.

Comment: Working with timezones is messy. May I recommend Jon Skeet's library NodaTime? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saeKBuPewcU https://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong timezone.  `"E. Australia Standard Time"` corresponds to Brisbane time, and that timezone does not observe DST so your winter and summer times come back with the same UTC offset.

For Sydney, you need to use `"AUS Eastern Standard Time"`.  `ConvertTimeFromUtc` will apply the UTC offset as appropriate for that timezone and give you the times you're expecting.

Here is your snippet including the use of the appropriate time zone, and a bit of editing around the Timezone initialisation so it compiled:

```
    public void ConvertTimes()
    {
        string Timezone = "AUS Eastern Standard Time";

        TimeZoneInfo ESTZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Timezone);
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-23 13:15:23.6090752");
        DateTime SydneyDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Timezone));
        string EST = SydneyDateTime.ToString() + " / " + SydneyDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime().ToString() + " / " + ESTZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(SydneyDateTime) + " / " + ESTZone.DaylightName + " / " + ESTZone.StandardName;
        DateTime IndiaDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));


        DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-23 13:15:23.6090752");
        DateTime SydneyDateTime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date2, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Timezone));
        string EST2 = SydneyDateTime2.ToString() + " / " + SydneyDateTime2.IsDaylightSavingTime().ToString() + " / " + ESTZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(SydneyDateTime2) + " / " + ESTZone.DaylightName + " / " + ESTZone.StandardName;
    }
```

This gives the output:

> EST = "24/01/2019 00:15:23 / False / True / AUS Eastern Daylight Time / AUS Eastern Standard Time"
>
> EST2 = "23/05/2019 23:15:23 / True / False / AUS Eastern Daylight Time / AUS Eastern Standard Time"

which I think is what you were expecting.

Incidentally, DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime() uses *your local* timezone to determine whether the time is within DST.  It might be misleading looking at it here.

Comment: By bad... Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that .Net does not consider AEST to be a timezone which uses daylight saving time. If I run the code below, the output indicates that CEST is daylight saving time but AEST is not:

```
    string timezone1 = "E. Australia Standard Time";
    string timezone2 = "Central European Standard Time";
    TimeZoneInfo info1 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone1);
    TimeZoneInfo info2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone2);
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-23 13:15:23.6090752");
    DateTime datetime1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone1));
    DateTime datetime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone2));
    var isDaylight1 = info1.IsDaylightSavingTime(datetime1);
    var isDaylight2 = info2.IsDaylightSavingTime(datetime2);
    Console.WriteLine(isDaylight1);
    Console.WriteLine(isDaylight2);
```

According to [www.timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aest), daylight saving time is optional in this region:

> Some places observe daylight saving time/summer time during the summer, and therefore use AEDT (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) in the summer.